# Entity framework core migration: Change column from non-nullable to nullable then set values to null

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I decided to change a column from non-nullable to a nullable one. No issue here. I changed the property to have "?" in the type (`DateTime` => `DateTime?`) and the migration generated is OK.

Though, I want to change the value considered as "null" to a real null. Meaning, changing the value `0001-01-01 00:00:00` to `null`.

I created an extension method that properly generated the SQL code for up and down. I executed this after the column change in `Up` and before in `Down`.

The issue comes when executing the `Up` because the SQL from my extension method is executed before the changes of the column alteration is applied.

Is there anyway to force changes to be apply before executing this statement? (See `FIXME` in the code where the code could be inserted. Two locations possible.)

**Extension class**

```
public static class MigrationsCorrections
{
    public static OperationBuilder<SqlOperation> ChangeDateToNullable(this MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder, string table, string column)
    {
        //FIXME: Either having a call here this to force previous changes to be applied
        return migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE {table} SET {column} = null WHERE {column} = '0001-01-01 00:00:00';");
    }

    public static OperationBuilder<SqlOperation> ChangeDateToNotNullable(this MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder, string table, string column)
    {
        return migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE {table} SET {column} = '0001-01-01 00:00:00' WHERE {column} = null;");
    }
}
```

**Migration class**

```
// IMPORTATION OF THE EXTENSION CLASS
public partial class MetaPersonBirthDateNullable : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "BirthDay",
            table: "MetaPersons",
            type: "TEXT",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
            oldType: "TEXT");
        //FIXME: Either having a call here this to force previous changes to be applied
        migrationBuilder.ChangeDateToNullable("MetaPersons", "BirthDay");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.ChangeDateToNotNullable("MetaPersons", "BirthDay");
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "BirthDay",
            table: "MetaPersons",
            type: "TEXT",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified),
            oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
            oldType: "TEXT",
            oldNullable: true);
    }
}
```

**SQL generated by migration**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE MetaPersons SET BirthDay = null WHERE BirthDay = '0001-01-01 00:00:00';

CREATE TABLE "ef_temp_MetaPersons" (
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_MetaPersons" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "BirthDay" TEXT NULL,
    "DeathDay" TEXT NULL,
    "ExternalId" TEXT NULL,
    "MetaSource" TEXT NULL,
    "Name" TEXT COLLATE NOCASE NULL,
    "Professions" TEXT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "ef_temp_MetaPersons" ("Id", "BirthDay", "DeathDay", "ExternalId", "MetaSource", "Name", "Professions")
SELECT "Id", "BirthDay", "DeathDay", "ExternalId", "MetaSource", "Name", "Professions"
FROM "MetaPersons";

COMMIT;

PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DROP TABLE "MetaPersons";

ALTER TABLE "ef_temp_MetaPersons" RENAME TO "MetaPersons";

COMMIT;

PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IX_MetaPersons_ExternalId_MetaSource" ON "MetaPersons" ("ExternalId", "MetaSource");

CREATE INDEX "IX_MetaPersons_Name" ON "MetaPersons" ("Name");

INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20220309145323_MetaPerson.BirthDate Nullable', '6.0.2');

COMMIT;
```

***As we can see, the `UPDATE` statement is not in the proper order***

**EDIT 1**

I tried using a MigrationOperation class instead as per [Microsoft Custom Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations), but I get...

*An operation of type 'ChangeDateToNullable' will be attempted while a rebuild of table 'MetaPersons' is pending. The database may not be in an expected state. Review the SQL generated by this migration to help diagnose any failures. Consider moving these operations to a subsequent migration.*

This particular solution is one I thought, having a second migration, but that's not what I would prefer as those changes are linked together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue pursuing in the direction of MigrationOperations. I overwrite  the Generate method of `IMigrationsSqlGenerator`.

For the sake of having a generalized solution, I created a new *Database* project that includes this new `MigrationsSqlGenerator` with the classes needed to change the date column value from/to null. I also added two classes to execute any SQL code that respect the order and thus enables changing the value of a column after altering it. And all this, in the same migration.

See https://github.com/djon2003/com.cyberinternauts.csharp.Database for the complete solution.

And https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5327089/Executing-SQL-code-within-EntityFrameworkCore-migr for the related article.

Final SQL code generated:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE "ef_temp_MetaPersons" (
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_MetaPersons" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "BirthDay" TEXT NULL,
    "DeathDay" TEXT NULL,
    "ExternalId" TEXT NULL,
    "MetaSource" TEXT NULL,
    "Name" TEXT COLLATE NOCASE NULL,
    "Professions" TEXT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "ef_temp_MetaPersons" ("Id", "BirthDay", "DeathDay", "ExternalId", "MetaSource", "Name", "Professions")
SELECT "Id", "BirthDay", "DeathDay", "ExternalId", "MetaSource", "Name", "Professions"
FROM "MetaPersons";

COMMIT;

PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DROP TABLE "MetaPersons";

ALTER TABLE "ef_temp_MetaPersons" RENAME TO "MetaPersons";

COMMIT;

PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IX_MetaPersons_ExternalId_MetaSource" ON "MetaPersons" ("ExternalId", "MetaSource");

CREATE INDEX "IX_MetaPersons_Name" ON "MetaPersons" ("Name");

UPDATE "MetaPersons" SET "BirthDay" = null WHERE "BirthDay" = '0001-01-01 00:00:00';

INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20220309145323_MetaPerson.BirthDate Nullable', '6.0.2');

COMMIT;
```

**As you can see, now the UPDATE statement is after the column alteration**

Comment: I strongly advise you to heed the warning and just use a subsequent migration instead. Overriding `SqliteMigrationsSqlGenerator` could easily become a maintainability nightmare for your application in the future.

Comment: @bricelam I am not overriding it. I am using a Decorator pattern. Did you look at the code?

Comment: No. I just read "new MigrationsSqlGenerator" and got scared. Out of curiosity, did you get the "a rebuild of table..is pending" warning when calling migrationBuilder.Sql? If not, can you [file a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose)?

Comment: @bricelam Yes I got the warning before using my new class. Would you like to give me your appreciation on this new class?

Comment: It's well-designed, but I still feel like it goes against the design of the Migrations feature. In your specific case, I'd just move the UPDATE operation *before* the ALTER operation. This allows it to execute before the rebuild. When that's not possible, (e.g. inserting NULL when a column still has NOT NULL) I'd sill recommend splitting it into two migrations. But I'm pretty bias since I'm the one who wrote the warning. ;-)

Comment: @bricelam I see now why you reacted like this! But, a concern I think that shall be think about is: A migration shall include anything related to it. I mean that change a column type and its value shall be in one migration. Otherwise, one could reverse only one of the migration even though both should be reversed or applied at the same time. Anyway, I know it's not something big, but that my bias. Hahaha!

Comment: A noble goal! (And one I generally agree with.)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [Using MigrationBuilder.Sql()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations#using-migrationbuildersql):

> Use the EXEC function when a statement must be the first or only one
> in a SQL batch. It might also be needed to work around parser errors
> in idempotent migration scripts that can occur when referenced columns
> don't currently exist on a table.

So better create two migrations, one for ALTER another for UPDATE.

Comment: I found a solution. See my answer and, if you want, tell me want you think.